# Where to use the return statement with a loop?

Tags: python, loops, return

Sometimes I get confused as to *where* to use the `return` statement. I get what it does, it's just that I don't get its placement properly.

Here's a short example of the same code.

Correct way:

```
def product_list(list_of_numbers):
    c = 1
    for e in list_of_numbers:
        c = c * e
    return c
```

Wrong way (which I did initially):

```
def product_list(list_of_numbers):
    c = 1
    for e in list_of_numbers:
        c = c * e
        return c
```

Can someone clarify what's the difference between the two and where should the `return` be when using a loop in a function?

Comment: Since `return` returns *the moment it is reached*, what do you think might happen to the remainder of the `for` loop iterations in the second version?

Comment: This comes down to understanding what makes a block in Python; do you understand how indentation determines what is part of the `for` loop or the `product_list` function?

Comment: `return` cause the function execution to stop and usually you use `for` loops to execute a code multiple times. If you put `return` in the inside of the `for` loop your code will stop executing immediately after the first `for` iteration, so that's why you want to put it outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: It's worth noting the reverse case in "Correct way". Whilst you do complete all of the iterations in your `for` loop as explained by others, you only `return` the value of `c` for the very last calculation. In which case, you might want to instead store all values of `c` in a list, and then return that list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it would run infinitely?

Comment: @Vayl: no, because the function ended when `return` is reached. So the `for` loop is still in its first iteration, and your `return` ends the function. The remainder of the loop iterations won't run now, ignoring the other values in `list_of_numbers`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, ah I see! So the return statement actually _ends_ a loop. When it's _outside_ the loop it only ends it when the loop completed fully. Sounds about right?

Comment: @Vayl The `return` statement ends the _function_ completely, not just the `for` loop. So anything after the `return` statement won't be executed either.

Comment: @Vayl: you got it! *Everything* in the function ends. The function itself ends, not just the loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks! :)

Comment: @Farhan.K, okay, that's a good thing to know too. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

`return` in a function means you are leaving the function immediately and returning to the place where you call it.
So you should use `return` when you are 100% certain that you wanna exit the function immediately.

In your example, I think you don't want to exit the function until you get the final value of c, so you should place the `return` outside of the loop.

Comment: Okay, so basically a for loop would run endlessly without a `return` statement. So in a way `return` is a bit like `break` but instead it returns a value?

Comment: @Vayl No it wouldn't run endlessly. It would still finish when it has iterated through everything in `list_of_numbers`. But it will end early (on the first iteration) if you put a `return` inside the loop.

Comment: @Vayl no, it wouldn't run endlessly. It would run for the exact number of iterations that you asked it to (in this case, the number of items in `list_of_numbers`). `return` inside the scope of a `for` loop happens to terminate the _function_, kicking you out of the `for` loop on the first iteration as something more like a byproduct of stopping the function.

Comment: No,the loop will end automatically after all elements in list_of_numbers have been visited.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting too much emphasis on the impact of `return` on controlling the behaviour of the `for` loop. Instead, `return` applies to the function and happens to terminate the `for` loop prematurely by primarily bringing an end to the function.

Instead, you can control the behaviour of the `for` loop independently from the function itself using `break`. In addition, you can have multiple `return` statements in a function depending on what action should be taken in response to particular criteria (as in `my_func1`). Consider the following:

```
import random

def my_func1(my_list, entry):
    ''' 
    Search a list for a specific entry. When found, terminate search 
    and return the list index immediately

    Return False if not found
    '''

    print "\n Starting func1"
    index = 0

    for item in my_list:
        if item != entry:
            print "Not found yet at index: {}".format(index)
            index += 1
        else:
            print "found item, at index {}".format(index)
            print "Terminating function AND loop at same time"
            return index

    print "########### ENTRY NOT IN LIST. RETURN FAlSE #############"
    return False


a = my_func1(['my', 'name', 'is', 'john'], 'is')
b = my_func1(['my', 'name', 'is', 'john'], 'harry')


def my_func2(my_list):
    ''' Iterate through a list
    For first 4 items in list, double them and save result to a list that will
    be returned, otherwise terminate the loop
    Also, return another list of random numbers
    '''
    print '\n starting func2'

    return_list = []
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if i < 4:
            print 'Value of i is {}'.format(i)
            return_list.append(my_list[i] * 2)
        else:
            print 'terminating for loop, but ** keep the function going **'
            break

    other_list = [random.randint(1, 10) for x in range(10)]

    print 'Returning both lists'
    return return_list, other_list

c = my_func2([x for x in range(10)])
```