# Python: For loop not working properly

Tags: python, django

Why is the for loop not working properly? It's just returned only one element.

1.

```
rx = ['abc', 'de fg', 'hg i']
def string_m(a=rx):
     for i in a:
         l = re.sub(" ","/",i)
         r = l.split("/")
         r.reverse()
         rx = " ".join(r)
         return rx
a=string_m(rx)
print(a)
```

Outputs:

```
abc
```

2.

```
rx = ['abc', 'de fg', 'hg i']
def string_m(a=rx):
     for i in a:
         l = re.sub(" ","/",i)
         r = l.split("/")
         r.reverse()
         rx = " ".join(r)
     return rx
a=string_m(rx)
print(a)
```

Outputs:

```
i hg
```

-- Can someone help me to see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is this supposed to do?

Comment: Indent your for loop so it's part of the function...

Comment: you need to maintain an intermediate list to store the reversed items

Comment: An almost identical question was answered earlier. See this for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702039/confused-as-to-where-to-use-return-statement-in-python/39703342#39702267

Comment: @AvinashRaj not with the reverse() method [docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_reverse.htm) Note that this is to be used on lists and not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

rx = ['abc', 'de fg', 'hg i']

def string_m(a=rx):
    new = []
    for i in a:
        l = re.sub(" ","/",i)
        r = l.split("/")
        #r.reverse()
        rx = " ".join(r)
        new.append(rx)
    new.reverse()
    return new

a=string_m(rx)
print(a)
```

Your biggest problem is that you return the result of the first iteration of your for loop instead of after the for loop has finished.

Another issue is that strings cannot be reversed with the reverse() method. If you want to reverse the output, Try the above.

Comment: The list `new` should be defined *inside* the function unless you want those strange side effects. You are right that you can't reverse a string in-place but he is reversing a list which totally works.

Answer (score 0):

```py
rx = ['abc', 'de fg', 'hg i']

def string_m(a=rx):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        rx = a[i]
            return rx

a=string_m(rx)
print(a)
```